# How to swap two words in a string?

Tags: python, string

I want to swap all occurrences of two words that appear within a really long string.

For example:

```
long_string = 'I eat food and she eat food so he can eat food'
```

I want to be able to change every occurrence of `"eat food"` into `"food eat"`:

```
'I food eat and she food eat so he can food eat'
```

Comment: Hello. Where is your code? Your forgot to add it.

Comment: So `great foods` shall really become `grfood eats`? (Judging by your acceptance of the answer that does this.)

Comment: @KellyBundy
Thank you for your notice! I've just edited the answer so it solves such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace)

```
long_string = 'I eat food and she eat food so he can eat food'

long_string = long_string.replace('eat food', 'food eat')

print(long_string)
```

> Output:
>
> I food eat and she food eat so he can food eat

#### Edit:1

As others pointed out if your strings would have something like **"great foods"** then you need to consider filtering with one space before and one after to avoid replacing **"great foods"**.

Also, if you consider the case where you get **"eat food"** at the beginning or at the end of your string, then appending one space to the beginning and to the end of the string solves the case.

```
long_string = " " + long_string + " "

long_string = long_string.replace(' eat food ', ' food eat ')
```

note that if you don't need the first and the last spaces added in the string, then consider removing them with:

```
long_string = long_string[1:-1]
```

#### Edit:2

As *@Tomerikoo & @Kelly Bundy* commented if you expect **punctuation** in the string. Then the solution would be:

```
import re
long_string = re.sub(r'\beat food\b', 'food eat', long_string)
```

###### Ref:

[regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

[re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: This doesn't take in count the fact that these are ***words***. i.e. (as mentioned in comments) `great foods` will become `grfood eats`

Comment: @Tomerikoo
Thank you for your suggestion! Well, that’s could be solved by finding the place where is exactly one space before `eat` and another one after `food` so that it becomes `replace(' eat food ', ' food eat ')`

Comment: What if the string exactly starts (or ends) with `"eat food"`? Maybe [regex](https://regex101.com/r/1wZtyx/1) ([`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)) would be a better option

Comment: The example in the question ends with `eat food` so your suggestion of the spaces gives the wrong output...

Comment: @Tomerikoo
Oh yes. How could you do it using regex?
Try this then!
`long_string.replace(' eat food ', ' food eat ').replace(' eat food', ' food eat').replace('eat food ', 'food eat ')`

Comment: See the link in my previous comment to regex101 (the word regex is a link)

Comment: The Edit:2 version turns `'great food man'` into `'grfood eat man'`. And `'eat eat eat food man'` into `'food eat eat eat man'`.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thank you for your notice. You give me a good hint to append one space to the beginning and the end of the original string and then it would be solved with just one `replace`. Please see the above again!!

Comment: Yes, now it looks ok for strings like their example (i.e., with just words separated by spaces, no punctuation).

Comment: @KellyBundy Do you have any better solution if the string has (punctuation)?

Comment: Tomerikoo's regex.

Comment: Yes, got it but I mean how to write as code?

Comment: Like the examples Tomerikoo linked to.

Comment: Your answer should be this  `re.sub(r'\beat food\b', 'food eat', long_string)`. Anyway, thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
long_string = 'I eat food and she eat food so he can eat food'
l = long_string.split(" ")
n = len(l)
flag = False
sorted_v = []

for idx in range(n-1):
    if l[idx] not in sorted_v and l[idx+1] not in sorted_v:
        for idx2 in range(idx+1, n-1):
            if l[idx] == l[idx2] and l[idx+1] == l[idx2+1]:
                l[idx2], l[idx2+1] = l[idx2+1], l[idx2]
                sorted_v.append(l[idx2+1])
                sorted_v.append(l[idx2])
                flag = True
    if flag:
        l[idx], l[idx + 1] = l[idx + 1], l[idx]
        flag = False

print(l)
```

Now some explanation is necessary. First of all, my idea was to make a list from the given string in order to easily swap elements (repeated word in this case). It is done with .split() method. Second step is to go through all the elements of previously created list and for each, check whether this element (word) is repeated somewhere. If so, if statement checks whether the following elements of these two currently checking elements are the same to determine whether we've found a repeated pair of elements. When all of this condition are met, we swap the elements compared. However, the elements from the outer loop are swaped later to keep the references, hence the flag variable to avoid swapping unnecessary elements. Sorted_v list is here to also avoid swapping the same  elements twice.

Answer (score 0):

Start by splitting long_string into tokens. The comparison string ('eat food') is assumed to contain exactly two whitespace delimited words. Then:

```
long_string = 'I eat food and she eat food so he can eat food'

def swap(s, t): # s is the original string. t is a 2-word string
    st = s.split()
    t1, t2 = t.split()
    for i, e in enumerate(st[:-1]):
        if e == t1 and st[i+1] == t2:
            st[i], st[i+1] = st[i+1], e
    return ' '.join(st)

print(swap(long_string, 'eat food'))
```

**Output:**

```
I food eat and she food eat so he can food eat
```

**Note:**

This **will** fail if the second parameter passed to swap() doesn't contain exactly two words/tokens